# awk to remove lines starting with symbol without keyword in them

Tags: awk

I am trying to selectively remove lines that start with `#` but do not contain the keywords `Build` or `Type` in them. The lines that do not start with `#` are unchanged. I can remove all lines that starting with `#` using the first `awk`, but not sure how to selectively remove lines that start with `#` but do not contain a keyword. The second `awk` does execute but only leaves two lines (#CN Filters:
                                   #  Flags = 1,2,3). Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk '!/#/' input < out  # will remove all lines with #
```

**awk**

```
awk '/#/ && !/Build|Length/' input < out  # remove lines starting with # but must not have Build or Length in them
```

**input**  `various spacing`

```
#Build = NCBI Build 37
#CN Filters:
#  Flags = 1,2,3
#  Type = Lowess
Length  Event   ID
1   Gain    xxx
10  Loss    yyy
```

**desired output**

```
Build = NCBI Build 37
Type = Lowess
Length  Event   ID
1   Gain    xxx
10  Loss    yyy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '!/^#/ || /Build|Type/' file
#Build = NCBI Build 37
#  Type = Lowess
Length  Event   ID
1   Gain    xxx
10  Loss    yyy
```

If you want to remove those initial `#` characters and the spaces after them:

```
$ awk '!/^#/ || /Build|Type/ { sub("^#[[:blank:]]*", ""); print }' file
Build = NCBI Build 37
Type = Lowess
Length  Event   ID
1   Gain    xxx
10  Loss    yyy
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do something with lines that start with `#` and do not contain `Build` or `Type`, right? I'm sure you could write that condition:

1. Start with `#` = `/^#/`
2. AND = `&&`
3. Do not contains `Build` or `Type` = `!/Build|Type/`

i.e.

```
/^#/ && !/Build|Type/
```

Now, what is it you wanted to do when that condition s true? Not print the current line. So you could just write that as simply:

```
awk '/^#/ && !/Build|Type/{next} 1'
```

but if you prefer to use awks default print given a true condition then you just need to negate your condition (`a{next} 1` = `!a`):

```
awk '!(/^#/ && !/Build|Type/)'
```

which by boolean algebra ( `!(a && b)` = `!a || !b`) can be reduced to:

```
awk '!/^#/ || /Build|Type/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same too.

```
awk '!(/^#/ && !/Build/ && !/Type/){gsub(/^#|^# +/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
!(/^#/ && !/Build/ && !/Type/){  ##Checking condition here if a line starts with # and NOT having string Build and Type in it, Negating this condition to work it as opposite, if this condition is TRUE then do following.
  gsub(/^#|^# +/,"");            ##Using gsub to remove hash in starting of a line OR remove a hash starting fr a line with space with NULL in current line.
  print                          ##Printing the current line here.
}' Input_file                    ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you both very much :).

Comment: @Chris, glad that it helped you, added explanation too here, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A sed solution:

```
$ sed 's/^# *\(.*\(Build\|Type\).*\)/\1/;/^#/d'  file
Build = NCBI Build 37
Type = Lowess
Length  Event   ID
1   Gain    xxx
10  Loss    yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/CN|Fl/{sub(/\43/,"")sub(/^\s*/,"");print}' file

Build = NCBI Build 37
Type = Lowess
Length  Event   ID
1   Gain    xxx
10  Loss    yyy
```